# How do you save a tag search for posts with a combination of tags?

Tags: support, search

How can I favorite a combination of tags? I usually have questions for running php on google app engine which I can find by searching for `[php] [google-app-engine]` but I can't figure out how to save this. When I create a new advanced search it looks up php or google-app-engine and I need it to be php and google-app-engine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+google-app-engine ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a search query, which happens as soon as you search for more tags, you can save the url in your browser as a bookmark, similar to what [Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255441/how-do-you-save-a-tag-search-for-posts-with-a-combination-of-tags#comment24916_255441) suggested.

I have a special query to go over some meta tags:

[`[discussion] answers:0 score:1 closed:no -[status-*] -[burninate-request] -[feature-request] -[retag-request] -[synonym-request]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5bdiscussion%5d%20answers%3a0%20score%3a1%20closed%3ano%20-%5bstatus-*%5d%20-%5bburninate-request%5d%20-%5bfeature-request%5d%20-%5bretag-request%5d%20-%5bsynonym-request%5d)

You can use the search options found in the right hand sidebar or in the [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) help page and bookmark the url.

With the introduction of the [new navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312434/a-quick-new-nav-update) you can now save your tags on the site:

[image: new nav]

Comment: how do you get to that save button? :O

Comment: @Sagivb.g that is gone now and replaced with new new nav ....

Comment: could you update your answer with a screenshot or an explanation of how to get there? i'm also trying to find a way to save a combination of tags, in my case of want to search `[tag1] or [tag2]` with a click of a button