# A quick new nav update

Tags: discussion, new-nav

**TL;DR: please help us test this version of new nav!**

---

**Update (Dec 17): We're holding off on the A/B test for now, but feel free to keep testing the new UI. We are a bit short of resources to work on this right now, so we will only be fixing critical bugs for the next 6-8 weeks.**

---

Since the last RC we have introduced the following requested changes:

- tabs are saved on the server, and will be the same across all browsers
- the page is pre-rendered on the server, this will eliminate the initial flicker
- tab autonaming has been slightly tweaked for consistency
- we won't show "explore our tabs" if you have any preference set, and when we do, it's on a single line
- we are hiding bounties on the homepage and meta
- slightly more filter/sort combos are available

The next step is for us to deploy to a subset of user and monitor the effect on answer rates. Alpha users will be excluded from the test, but will continue to see the new navigation as today.

Please use the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) tag for any bug report.

---

*Note:* For the existing alpha users, this upgrade means that **if you want to maintain your current saved tabs, they will need to be upgraded**. In order to do so, go to the upgrade pages on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/home/upgrade-tabs) and [main](https://stackoverflow.com/home/upgrade-tabs). New alpha testers (added today) will not have any locally saved tabs.

[image: tab upgrade]

<sup>*We won't support this service for long, if it breaks, or is not available, you will need to recreate your tabs manually*</sup>

Comment: No title on meta http://i.stack.imgur.com/yP8KM.png  Twas there 10 mins ago... Should I add a bug report?

Comment: So the main upgrade link doesn't work for me.  I get a 404.  But the meta one seemed to work.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I am deploying it right now

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze ah thanks.  Yeah it worked now.

Comment: @BhargavRao, nah, I've got it

Comment: Yikes! The new deployment just made it look like tabs stopped working, period. I figured I should scan meta quickly before filing a bug report, and found this post. If there was a warning anywhere that should have shown up when by tabs went dead, I did not see it. (For the record: I did the upgrade. My tabs work now.)

Comment: @BhargavRao it should be fixed now.

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze Yes. Thanks.

Comment: [This problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311146/tabs-with-multiple-tags-automatically-become-modified) seems to be fixed in this update (Edge) but a new one has popped up. Pressing F5 on a multiple-tags tab opens a new tab with the same tags applied and when you click a single tag tab the new tab disappears

Comment: "slightly more filter/sort combos are available" can I use AND and OR operators in a single query?

Comment: @Braiam yes, but this is not new. Keep in mind that we don't support brackets.

Comment: Should this have affected the pagination links? They do not seem to be working anymore (for me, anyway).

Comment: so now we can only save one tag per tab @EbenezerSklivvze as its not working for more then one

Comment: @TiesonT. fixed in the next build

Comment: @saurabhkamble fixed in the next build

Comment: @Sklivvz How to test the new nav?

Comment: Any idea how long we have to wait to test this been on the waiting list for ages... don't want to un-check and check the option again for fear I get put to the back of the queue. @Stephen you can opt-in on the `Edit Profile & Settings` -> `Site Settings` -> `Preferences` -> `New Navigation` section of your profile - `I would like to participate in testing the new navigation.`.

Comment: Wow, it's now showing the new nav! Thank you.

Comment: Magic! I thought it would autoadd people on demand, but there were still 2000 users waiting.

Comment: @Sklivvz is there any timeframe for when this will be rolled out to the rest of the network? :) (I couldn't find a more recent post which is why I'm commenting here :/)