# custom tabs gone since 15-Dec-2015

Tags: bug, new-nav

it seems my custom tags are gone. I last saw them yesterday 15-Dec-2015 @ ca. 19:30 CET ... Today morning 16-Dec-2015 @ca. 11:15 CET they didn't show up. I verified that I was signed on both times.

Can anyone advise whether I should

- wait for my tabs to appear again
- recreate my tabs
- expect this to happen more often during "test phase" and go back to use "my favourite tags"

[image: Screen shot 16-Dec-2015 11:45 CET]

Screen shot 16-Dec-2015 11:45 CET

Thanks

Mike

Comment: [Go to this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312434/a-quick-new-nav-update) and use the links to upgrade tabs

Comment: @Steve problem solved ... thank you ... this worked perfectly

Comment: Yeah a case of ...unsuspecting victims....

Comment: no problem ... I knew that this is test phase ... good job anyway!